# SQL Display conditionally on other row

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, sql-server-2016

I have a table that lists a batch number and then results from testing at each stage that this batch passes through.

I want to display test results for each stage, but only on batches which have passed a certain stage in the last 7 days.

So far I have in my WHERE the following:

```
WHERE [DateTime] >= DATEDIFF(dd,7,GETDATE())
  AND Stage IN ('4','5')
  AND FVBatch LIKE '3%'

GROUP BY FVBatch, [DateTime], Stage, Brand
```

This shows me the batches that I want to display, but it only shows the last 2 stages. I would like to be able to do apply this condition on the stage column but then also display the 3 previous stages for these batches.

The below image shows the results from the above query. What I would like is for it to also show the results for stages 1, 2 & 3

[image]

Comment: Can you include some sample data?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. I'll edit the question.

Comment: To ask the obvious, is removing the `Stage IN ('4','5')` condition not acceptable to you?

Comment: It would then display all of the batches regardless of which stage they are in. There are several batches which have not yet reached stage 4 or 5 which I don't want displayed.

Comment: So you want all stages of batches only which have reached 4 or 5?  Is that right?

Comment: yes exactly, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only batches having 4 or 5

```
..
FROM ttable t1
WHERE [DateTime] >= DATEDIFF(dd,7,GETDATE()) -- are you sure? [DateTime] >= DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE())
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ttable t2 WHERE t2.FVBatch = t1.FVBatch AND t2.Stage IN ('4','5'))
  AND FVBatch LIKE '3%'

GROUP BY FVBatch, [DateTime], Stage, Brand
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT FVBatch, [DateTime], Stage, Brand       -- this inner query
    FROM yourTable                                 -- will retain only
    WHERE Stage IN ('4','5')                       -- groups having
    GROUP BY FVBatch, [DateTime], Stage, Brand     -- stages 4 and 5
    HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT Stage) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.FVBatch    = t2.FVBatch    AND
       t1.[DateTime] = t2.[DateTime] AND
       t1.Stage      = t2.Stage      AND
       t1.Brand      = t2.Brand
WHERE t1.[DateTime] >= DATEDIFF(dd,7,GETDATE()) AND
      t1.FVBatch LIKE '3%'
```